# Use of Multiple Inheritance in EclipseLink MOXy

Tags: spring, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to use spring (`@Autowire` annotation into Jaxb Model class)

```
.....

@XmlAttribute(name = "object-id")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "positiveInteger")
protected BigInteger objectId;

@XmlTransient
@Autowired MediationCacheManager cacheManager;
```

Where `MediationCacheManager` is extended from three interfaces

On creation of JaxbContext i catch an exception:
 `Exception [EclipseLink-50089] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20121116-8650760): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The java interface com.netcracker.mediation.common.caches.api.MediationCacheManager can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces. Multiple inheritence is not supported`

Of course i understand that eclipselink doesn't support multiple inheritance but how can i skip `cacheManager` field from Jaxb processing? As for me - it should be done by `XmlTransient` annotation but its no work. Have u any idea?

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399333/xml-transient-not-working-jaxbmoxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing corresponds to a bug (http://bugs.eclipse.org/411993) that we have fixed in the EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.0 streams.  You can download a nightly build from the following link starting July 4, 2013:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

**WORKAROUND**

You can use MOXy's external mapping document to override the supertype of `MediationCacheManager` to make your use case work (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html):

***oxm.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum17458822">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="MediationCacheManager" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

***Demo***

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum17458822/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);
    }

}
```